# The Power Of Not Mutating Data and Assignment Destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variable-assignment, destructuring

I'm writing `reactjs` and I want to use [The Power Of Not Mutating Data](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data).
In code below `this.state.messages['hydra:member']` is an array of objects and I want to know that in this code `messages` is a reference to `this.state.messages['hydra:member']` or a new array.
 If I mutate it `this.state.messages['hydra:member']` will change or not?

```
let {'hydra:member': messages = []} = this.state.messages;
```

and what about this:

```
if(this.state.messages['hydra:member'] !== undefined) {
    let messages = this.state.messages['hydra:member'];
}
```

Comment: "*and a copy of*" - what do you mean?

Comment: Your second code doesn't make any sense, as the `let` variable is confined to the `if` block that doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: where are you trying to do this exactly, what is the context of your problem ?

Comment: @MohammadZareMoghadam it's a reference of course. No operator implicitly clones objects in JS.

Comment: Is `let messages` a reference or a clone? If I mutate it `this.state.messages['hydra:member'] ` will change or not? @adz5a

Answer (score 0):

To create a deep copy of `this.state.messages['hydra:member']` you can do as follows

```
if(this.state.messages['hydra:member'] !== undefined) {
    let messages = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.messages['hydra:member']));
   //use messages here
}
```

Now, when you use the messages array you will not be mutating the state.

Comment: I know this but I want to know that can I do this with "Assignment Destructuring"?

Comment: That's a pretty expensive way of doing a deep copy.

Comment: @Ouroborus I am going by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074  Discaimer: I have not personally tested the efficiency of the solution with compared to others.